# GoKit and generating microservices install protoc error

Tags: api, go

The error shows me this

> 1. I already downloaded those packages.
> 2. still show me the error Please install protoc first and than rerun the command

```
$ kit generate service notifactor -t grpc --dmw
time="2019-03-06T16:35:29+08:00" level=error msg="Please install protoc first and than rerun the command"
time="2019-03-06T16:35:29+08:00" level=info msg="Install proto3.\nhttps://github.com/google/protobuf/releases\nUpdate protoc Go bindings via\n> go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/proto\n> go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go\n\nSee also\nhttps://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples"
```

Comment: is protoc in PATH?

Comment: Do you mean in my Environment Variables? @SauravPrakash

Comment: Gotta love a library that doesn't know the difference between "then" and "than" :P

Comment: yes, is `protoc` in your PATH env var?

Comment: @SauravPrakash no I downloaded it but didn't add in my PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [go-kit source](https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/transport/grpc):

> Using gRPC and go-kit together is very simple.
>
> First, define your service using protobuf3. This is explained in gRPC documentation. See add.proto for an example. Make sure the proto definition
>   matches your service's go-kit (interface) definition.
>
> Next, get the protoc compiler.
>
> You can download pre-compiled binaries from the protobuf release page. You will unzip a folder called protoc3 with a subdirectory bin containing an executable. Move that executable somewhere in your $PATH and you're good to go!

So just make sure protoc is in your PATH env var.